# How do i know if teamviewer executed successfully and get the session id and password?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, viewer

I am trying to run TeamViewer in a headless ubuntu OS. The OS is running as amazon ec2 AMI so I have no physical access to it. Currently, I just type the command "teamviewer" in ssh and the only output I get is something like:

> TeamViewer: 6.0.9258
>
> Profile: /home/ubuntu (ubuntu)
>
> Desktop:
>
> No LSB modules are available.
>
> Distributor ID: Ubuntu
>
> Description:    Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS
>
> Release:        10.04
>
> Codename:       lucid
>
> Checking setup...
>
> Launching c:\Program Files\TeamViewer\Version6\TeamViewer.exe...

Did it launch successfully? If so, how can I know the session id and password so that I can connect to it from another machine?

Comment: Try "man teamwiever" and look if there is a command for it.

Answer (score 4):

Given that you have a running X server (or Xvfb) and DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY are set properly, TeamViewer should start.

`cat ~/.teamviewer/7/logfiles/TeamViewer7_Logfile.log | grep '^ID:'` will give you the ID, but does not work on the first start. (The logfile symlink is created on the second launch). Of course you can also use the logfile to see if it started up properly. Wine problems are logged to `~/.teamviewer/7/logfiles/winelog`)

To get ID and password, taking a screenshot really is the simplest solution. Like above, DISPLAY and Xauthority must be properly set. Then,

```
xwd -name TeamViewer | xwdtopnm | pnmtopng > tvscreen.png
```

will do the trick.

**[Edit]**

In TeamViewer 8 and above, the screenshot trick is not needed.
From the command line, a password can be set and the ID can be printed
See:

```
teamviewer --help
teamviewer --info
teamviewer --passwd [PASSWD]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea for a general strategy:

You could try to grep the process-list for the ProcessID of wine TeamViewer.exe, take a screenshot of the window belonging to that process, save it to an image with a filename of your choice, and then download that image.

People have attempted to do similar things, (but in this case not with teamviewer, and on windows).
[How to get window's HWND from it's process handle?](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=392273)

Answer (score -1):

teamviewer doesn't work if xorg is not running.

Comment: Seriously, it doesn't work without xorg. Teamviewer works through wine, there is no native client of teamviewer for linux...